# Can you give me an example of "A is closed subset of X (metric space) but A' doesn't equal to A "?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

i'm studying topology and i learnt a thm saying

```
For (X,d) metric space, A is a subset of X
then A is a closed subset of X if and only if the derivative set of A is included in A.

i.e. A⊆X closed ⟺ A'⊆A
```

I understood the proof but I can't think of any example that A is closed but the limit point set does not equal to A. Can you give an example?

Thank you

Comment: It seems that any possible example will involve isolated points. For, if $E$ is any closed set, then $E$ consists of only two (mutually exclusive) varieties of points: isolated points or limit points. Of course it need not have either, for $\emptyset$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the set $\{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ under the usual topology. It has no limit points, only isolated ones, so $\{0\}' = \varnothing$

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $A=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$, as a subset of $\Bbb R$, endowed with its usual metric. Then $A'=\{0\}\varsubsetneq A$.

Comment: Thank you for your help:)